# Pandas, removing duplicate datetime hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this.

```
       timestamp         avg_hr  avg_rr    emfit_sleep_summary_id   AVG_HR    AVG_RR
 2015-01-28 08:14:50     101     6.4                      78         99.5       6.4 
 2015-01-28 08:14:52      98     6.4                      78         99.5       6.4
 2015-01-28 00:25:00      60     0.0                      78         61.5       0.0
 2015-01-28 00:25:02      63     0.0                      78        61.5       0.0
 2015-01-28 07:24:06      79    11.6                      78        78.5       11.6
 2015-01-28 07:24:08      79    11.6                      78        78.5       11.6
```

Where the timestamp is the index. I'm trying to remove the duplicate timestamp (by hours) so instead of the above table I'm trying to get something like the following.

```
      timestamp         avg_hr  avg_rr    emfit_sleep_summary_id    AVG_HR    AVG_RR
 2015-01-28 08:14:50     101     6.4                      78         99.5       6.4 
 2015-01-28 00:25:02      63     0.0                      78         61.5       0.0
 2015-01-28 07:24:08      79    11.6                      78         78.5       11.6
```

I've tried the following.

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=df2.index.hour,take_last=True)
```

but that returns a s `Keyerror: 22`

And I also tried: `df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=df2.index,take_last=True)`

which returns, `KeyError: Timestamp('2015-03-31 22:29:48')`

any advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reset the index so that it becomes a column, this allows you to call `apply` on it, then for each datetime apply a lambda which calls `replace` and null the minute and seconds attributes, then drop the duplicates and set the index back:

```
In [51]:

df = df.reset_index()
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=0, second=0))
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='timestamp', take_last=True)
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df
Out[51]:
                     avg_hr  avg_rr  emfit_sleep_summary_id  AVG_HR  AVG_RR
timestamp                                                                  
2015-01-28 08:00:00      98     6.4                      78    99.5     6.4
2015-01-28 00:00:00      63     0.0                      78    61.5     0.0
2015-01-28 07:00:00      79    11.6                      78    78.5    11.6
```

Answer (score 4):

Use resample:

```
In [52]:

df.resample('H', how='first').dropna(how='all')
Out[52]:
                    avg_hr  avg_rr  emfit_sleep_summary_id  AVG_HR  AVG_RR
timestamp                   
2015-01-28 00:00:00 60      0.0                         78  61.5    0.0
2015-01-28 07:00:00 79      11.6                        78  78.5    11.6
2015-01-28 08:00:00 101     6.4                         78  99.5    6.4
```

The reason for using `.dropna()` is that an hourly resample will create rows for each hour between the first and last which will be filled with NaNs if there is no data within the hour.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem - had dates as index and double entries.

I solved it with boolean filtering (Probably not the most elegant, but it did the job):

```
df = df.reset_index()[df.reset_index()["index"].duplicated() != True].set_index("index", drop = True)
```